# Optimization problem with ratio objective

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I need to solve the following optimization problem

$$
\text{maximize} \quad \frac{(a^T x)^2}{x^TBx+c^T|x|} \quad \text{subject to} \quad \|x\|_1=1 \quad (\text{or alternatively} \quad c^T|x|=1), 
$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the optimization variable, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $a,c \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The matrix $B$ is positive-semidefinite and symmetric, the vectors $a$ and $c$ are non-negative.

Can this optimization problem be transformed into a tractable quadratic programm? Which numerical optimization method is best suited for this problem?

Cheers
R.

Comment: This could be promising, but I only took a quick look at it: http://www-optima.amp.i.kyoto-u.ac.jp/result/masterdoc/19zhang.pdf

Comment: I seems that nonlinear fractional programming is a well-known problem . However, the sticking point here is the absolute value in the denominator.

Comment: Does this help, together with my first link: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76420/quadratic-problem-solving-with-absolute-value-constraint ?

Comment: Do we at least know that $B$ is positive definite and the entries of $c$ are non-negative?

Comment: @fedja Yes, B is positive definite and c are non-negative. Furthermore the constraint |x|=1 can be substituted by c^T|x|=1.

Comment: I don't see why $c^T|x|=1$. If $c = (2,0)$ and $x =(1,0)$ this is not true.

Comment: $c^T|x|=1$ is meant to be an alternative constraint not an equivalent constraint to $||x||_1=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trust region or line search methods to deal with nonlinear objective funstion.